# Wired connection drops occasionally - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, configuration

I've having random drops in my wired connection.
When using Windows on the same laptop - no drops.

Not sure what do to, or which logs\configuration to post here,
so if any more info is needed please ask and i'll update the post.

ifconfig:

```
enp5s0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d0:2b:b8:04:c4  
      inet addr:192.168.1.26  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:39105 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:30631 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:29969787 (29.9 MB)  TX bytes:6485444 (6.4 MB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:5876 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5876 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:579858 (579.8 KB)  TX bytes:579858 (579.8 KB)

wlp4s0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:0a:64:63:84:77  
      inet addr:192.168.1.30  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::49fa:f591:4f59:15fd/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8256 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:599 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2653633 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:110394 (110.3 KB)
```

Here's `/var/log/syslog`, from around the time of some drop:

```
424 Dec 29 18:02:09 adiel-N550JV systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
425 Dec 29 18:02:09 adiel-N550JV dbus[1011]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
426 Dec 29 18:02:09 adiel-N550JV systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
427 Dec 29 18:02:09 adiel-N550JV nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp4s0]: new request (1 scripts)
428 Dec 29 18:02:09 adiel-N550JV nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp4s0]: start running ordered scripts...
429 Dec 29 18:02:51 adiel-N550JV wpa_supplicant[1151]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
430 Dec 29 18:04:51 adiel-N550JV wpa_supplicant[1151]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
431 Dec 29 18:05:45 adiel-N550JV dhclient[7340]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.14 on enp5s0 to 192.168.1.1 port 67 (xid=0x77a2b8cc)
432 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV dhclient[7340]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.14 on enp5s0 to 192.168.1.1 port 67 (xid=0x77a2b8cc)
433 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV dhclient[7340]: DHCPNAK from 192.168.1.1 (xid=0xccb8a277)
434 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1489] dhcp4 (enp5s0): state changed bound -> expire
435 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1652] dhcp4 (enp5s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 7340
436 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1653] dhcp4 (enp5s0): state changed expire -> done
437 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1654] device (enp5s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ip-config-expired') [100 120 6]
438 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1656] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
439 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV whoopsie[970]: [18:05:48] offline
440 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <warn>  [1483027548.1794] device (enp5s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
441 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV dbus[1011]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
442 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1805] device (enp5s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
443 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV avahi-daemon[927]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.14 on enp5s0.
444 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV avahi-daemon[927]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp5s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.14.
445 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV avahi-daemon[927]: Interface enp5s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
446 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1820] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
447 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1821] policy: set 'Bidani' (wlp4s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
448 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV dnsmasq[1451]: setting upstream servers from DBus
449 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1822] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
450 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV dnsmasq[1451]: using nameserver 213.57.22.5#53
451 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1877] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'
452 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV dnsmasq[1451]: using nameserver 213.57.2.5#53
453 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1883] device (enp5s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (397c5b6c-907f-312d-95ee-c95be2163114)
454 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1884] device (enp5s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
455 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1887] device (enp5s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
456 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1890] device (enp5s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
457 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1892] dhcp4 (enp5s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
458 Dec 29 18:05:48 adiel-N550JV NetworkManager[1025]: <info>  [1483027548.1901] dhcp4 (enp5s0): dhclient started with pid 9082
```

**UPDATE:**

`sudo lshw -C network` output:

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlp4s0
   version: 01
   serial: 24:0a:64:63:84:77
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-57-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.26 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:18 memory:f7900000-f797ffff memory:f7980000-f798ffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: enp5s0
   version: 0c
   serial: 74:d0:2b:b8:04:c4
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.041.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:32 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7800000-f7800fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
```

Comment: Your network driver is up to date?

Comment: @vembutech, how do i check this under ubuntu? im used to windows :\

Comment: using apt-get update && apt-get upgrade says all packages are updated

Comment: Using the `terminal` app, show us the output of `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: ps: I suspect that you're using the funky r8169 driver... but I need to see the lshw command that I requested, before I can tell you the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `sudo lshw -C network`, using the `terminal` app.

Confirm that the driver in use for your enp5s0 ethernet device is `r8169`. This driver is the cause of your network drops.

If it is `r8169` then:

In `terminal`...

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install dkms`
- `sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms`
- `reboot`

Comment: The driver is indeed r8168. i've followed your instructions and i'll see if i'm experiencing any more drops.

Could this suggested method could be useful for the wifi adapter as well, if drops occur with it?
its driver is `ath9k, version: 4.4.0-57-generic11bgn`

Thanks

Comment: Was your original driver r8169 or r8168? Does your comment have a typo? Wireless problems are varied. Start a new question if you need to.

Comment: Oh. I think ive missed that in your comment, i thought both numbers you've written was the same. My original driver was `r8168`

Comment: I've now updated to the latest driver: `8.0.43` by Realtek. Will see if that'll work